# Delete all duplicates in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table. It has been imported from CSV, it does not have a primary key.

```
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
| firstname | lastname | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
| johnny    | bravo    | a  | b  | c  |
| bruce     | willis   | x  | y  | x  |
| john      | doe      | p  | q  | r  |
| johnny    | bravo    | p  | q  | r  |
| johnny    | bravo    | p  | q  | r  |
| bruce     | willis   | x  | y  | z  |
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
```

I want to delete all rows where (firstname, lastname) appear more than once in the table. So the output would be:

```
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
| firstname | lastname | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
| john      | doe      | p  | q  | r  |
+-----------+----------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, the best way is to use `join`:

```
delete t
from t join
(
    select t2.firstname, t2.lastname
    from t t2
    group by t2.firstname, t2.lastname
    having count(*) > 1
) t2
    on t.firstname = t2.firstname and
       t.lastname = t2.lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select as following instead of delete.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(firstname) AS num
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
) B ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.LastName = B.LastName
WHERE B.num = 1
```

But if you wanna delete then do as following

```
DELETE A 
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(firstname) AS num
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
) B ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.LastName = B.LastName
WHERE B.num > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_name n 
where (select count(*) from table_name z 
where n.firstname  = z.firstname  and n.lastname  = z.lastname) > 1
```